# Tortoise SVN: export ONLY the files modified in a changeset

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to export from the Repository to a specific folder **only** the files which were modified by a changeset.

The folder is **not** the main SVN folder (workingcopy).

Is it possible?

Comment: It'd probably help if you could rephrase your question using Subversion terminology (update, checkout or export rather than download, working copy or repository rather than folder...). But you should probably start at the "SVN Show log" menu item.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: I've tried to better clarify but I'm not sure about what is Export.. I am trying to check.

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure seems to do what you want: 
http://verysimple.com/2007/09/06/using-tortoisesvn-to-export-only-newmodified-files/